# How does 'in' clause works in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

```
select 'true' from dual where 1 not in (null,1);
```

when we execute this which will result nothing

what my question is:

is the above query is logically equivalent to

```
select 'true' from dual where 1 != null and 1 != 1;
```

which will result nothing just as above statement

Please clarify?

Comment: Yes, `NOT IN()` is logically equivalent to a chain of `!= AND !=`.

Comment: And the positive condition `IN()` is equivalent to a chain of `OR =`

Comment: careful with NULLs in your list.  NOT IN will not return rows due to the NULL.  Many discussions on NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS that show the effect of NULLs.

Comment: @ypercube the issue is with NOT IN and nulls.  I mention NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS because there are a lot of good articles that discuss the differences in how each treat nulls.  One example: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Correct (but note that `IN` is an operator, not a clause and it works like this in SQL in general, not only for Oracle).

```
where 1 not in (null,1)
```

is equivalent to:

```
where 1 != null and 1 != 1
```

which should really be written as:

```
WHERE 1 NOT IN (NULL, 1)
```

and

```
WHERE 1 <> NULL AND 1 <> 1
```

which is the same as:

```
WHERE (1 <> NULL) AND (1 <> 1)
```

which evaluates to:

```
WHERE UNKNOWN AND FALSE
```

and further as:

```
WHERE FALSE
```

So, it correctly returns no rows.

---

Notice that if you had `WHERE 1 NOT IN (NULL, 2)`, it would evaluate to `WHERE UNKNOWN` (left as an exercise) and no rows would be returned either.

Answer (score 4):

The issue of your script in comparing with NULL value. You should use

```
column is null and column = 1
```

Actually NULL is an undefined value. Any comparation with NULL gives neither True nor False but NULL. Even *NULL = NULL*

That's why your *1 not in (null,1)* doesn't work.

Comment: The result is `False` actually, in this case (because of the `1` in the list).

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are.

```
select something from table where column not in (1,2,3);
```

is equivalent to

```
select something from table where column != 1 and column != 2 and column != 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN statement is a collection of OR statements, while NOT IN is a collection of AND statements - but it is also not equal to.

So the NOT IN is equivalent to:

```
1 <> NULL
AND 1 <> 1
AND ...
```

While the IN would be equivalent to:

```
1 = NULL
OR 1 = 1
OR ...
```

Note that having NULL in the collection will not work, due to the quirky nature of NULL.

Comment: @is that mean when the collection contains atleast one null than we cant go with IN clause?

Comment: I am not sure how you are passing the values in, but for NULL you will need to explicitly have "AND A IS NOT NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is correct. Also NULL values should be compared with IS NULL